# Função recursiva de Inserir nós

Tags: c, árvore-binária

Analisando outros problemas , percebi a necessidade de ultilizar ponteiros de ponteiros em determinadas funções de árvores. Logo, defini a função de Inserção como :

```
Arvore* insereNo (Arvore** A, int chave)
```

A questão é que posteriormente, na hora de inserir novos nós, existe um problema quanto á chamada da função :

```
if (chave < (*A)->chave){
  (*A)->esq = insereNo((*A)->esq, chave);
}

else {
  (*A)->dir = insereNo((*A)->dir, chave);
}
```

Como proceder com os ponteiros ? Deixarei o código um pouco mais completo, para melhor percepção (lembrando que este é um esboço para árvore rubro-negra).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRETO 1
#define VERMELHO 0

struct No {

  int cor;
  int chave;
  struct No* esq, *dir;
  struct No* pai;

} No;

typedef struct No Arvore;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Arvore* insereNo (Arvore** A, int chave){

  struct No* novo = (struct No*)malloc(sizeof(struct No));

  if (novo == NULL){
      return NULL;
  }

  novo->chave = chave;
  novo->esq = NULL;
  novo->dir = NULL;
  novo->cor = VERMELHO;

  if ( *A == NULL){
      *A = novo;
      return *A;
  }

  if ( chave == (*A)->chave){
      free(novo);
      return NULL;
  }

  else {

      if (chave < (*A)->chave){
          (*A)->esq = insereNo((*A)->esq, chave);
      }

      else {
          (*A)->dir = insereNo((*A)->dir, chave);
      }
  }

  return (*A);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int main(){

  Arvore* A = NULL;

  insereNo(&A, 10);
  insereNo(&A, 11);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É o seguinte,  a sua função insereNo recebe como parâmetro um endereço de um ponteiro, e um inteiro. Portanto em `insereNo((*A)->esq, chave)` e `insereNo((*A)->dir, chave` deveria ser `insereNo(&((*A)->esq), chave)` e `insereNo(&((*A)->dir), chave)`.

E lembre-se que sua função `insereNo` retorna um ponteiro, portanto na sua função main deve ser `A = insereNo(&A, 10);` e `A = insereNo(&A, 11);`

Além disso, você está fazendo `return (*A)` no final da sua função `insereNo`, isso vai dar segmentation fault. O correto seria `return novo`.